# network namespace TCP microfreeze

Tags: python, linux, networking

I am running a python app in a different network namespace and it opens a TCP connection to a websocket. The problem is that this connection has microfreezes. It would run fine for a minute approximately and then it would hang for a second. I think it's the network namespace problem because if I run outside it there is no problem.

I monitored the TCP buffers with `ss -tm` and what I notice is that when the freeze starts, the buffers also start to fill up. They seem to be empty the rest of the time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the app tried to connect to a localhost socket. It failed
because that socket is open with the main ip and not in the network namespace.
Because the app is written in python it would hang while trying to connect.

Comment: How does that explain the odd timing you observed?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess it filled up the tcp buffers waiting to timeout that connection. We removed it and it started working fine.

Comment: I figured out the problem after all. I didn't mention that the app was written in python. That localhost connection wasn't in a async function so it would block the app.

Comment: You have edite the tags above accordingly; if you update your self-answer with this info I might upvote both question and answer ;)